# How can I process child nodes the same way as parent nodes using multiple files as input in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am currently trying to process multiple files for specific nodes and collect them in a meaningful way to demonstrate the parent-child relationship but I'm having trouble getting past the first level of children.

A little background:

I'm attempting to collect procedure codes from a service manual. The manual is composed of several XMLs. The procedures these codes refer to sometimes refer to subprocedures, which in turn may refer to subprocedures. I want to list out all the procedure codes. If there is a subprocedure referenced in a procedure, I want to list its code as a child and continue in this way for all subprocedure until a procedure is listed that does not include a subprocedure.

So far, it's really easy for me to:

- process all procedures (contained in a file list)
- list the frt number for the procedure
- from a given procedure, process all `xref` nodes found in `cmd` nodes and list the `@keyref` value.

The `@keyref` value is the same as the `@id` of the procedure to which it references. So, in a given procedure, any `cmd/xref/@keyref` value basically refers to a subprocedure. What I am attempting to capture is a list of all the `@id` values for procedures with subprocedures, and in turn, the `@id` of procedures that are subprocedures to subprocedures. I want to do this in a tree that makes the parent/child/descendant relationship clear in terms of what additional procedures someone needs to perform when performing a given procedure.

Something like this:

```
<service-manual>
  <procedure>
     <name>3 Way Coolant Valve - Chiller Bypass (Remove and Replace)</name>
     <frt-num>1234</frt-num>
     <child-proc>
        <frt-num>10040401</frt-num>
        <child-proc>
           <frt-num>3456</frt-num>
           ...
        </child-proc>
        <child-proc>
           <frt-num>4567</frt-num>
           ...
        </child-proc>
     </child-proc>
     <child-proc>
        <frt-num>15240701</frt-num>
        <child-proc>
           <frt-num>1111</frt-num>
           ...
        </child-proc>
        <child-proc>
           <frt-num>2222</frt-num>
           ...
        </child-proc>
     </child-proc>         
     ...
  </procedure>
...
```

What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to process all the procedures an `xref` refers to and list its children. What it needs to do is:

- Figure out which `task` to which a given `@keyref` refers.
- List the `@id` of that `task` as a child to the current context.
- Continue processing all the `@keyrefs` in the same way in the decedent chain.

The result that I'm getting from my style sheet is only processing the first set of children.

Few things about this:

- In all cases, the outermost `task` node is the only relevant `@id` value I'm concerned with. Nested `task` nodes do not factor into this exercise.
- I want to capture all of this in a single XML.
- There are over 500 files referenced in the file list. So, I am just offering a partial sample here.

The source XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE task
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Task//EN" "task.dtd">
<task id="X1234">
   <title>3 Way Coolant Valve - Chiller Bypass (Remove and Replace)</title>
   <taskbody>
      <prereq>
         <p><b>FRT No: 1234</b></p>
         <note conref="../../resources/SM-reuse.dita#topic_nsx_hq3_sl/Jack-Mode-Before-Lifting"/>
         <p conref="../../resources/SM-reuse.dita#topic_nsx_hq3_sl/12v-warnings"/>
      </prereq>
   </taskbody>
   <task id="d1e41176">
      <title><ph conref="../../resources/SM-reuse.dita#topic_nsx_hq3_sl/removal-title"/></title>
      <taskbody>
         <steps>
            <step>
               <cmd>Some content for the step <xref keyref="X10040401">(refer to procedure)</xref>. </cmd>
            </step>
            <step>
               <cmd><ph conref="../../resources/SM-reuse.dita#topic_nsx_hq3_sl/disconnect-12v"
                  /></cmd>
            </step>
            <step>
               <cmd>Some content for the steps <xref keyref="X15240701">(refer to
                     procedure)</xref>.</cmd>
            </step>
            <step>
               <cmd>Some content for the step</cmd>
            </step>
            <step>
               <cmd>Some content for the step</cmd>
            </step>
            <step>
               <cmd>Some content for the step</cmd>
               <stepxmp>
                  <fig>
                     <xref href="repairimages/tss00168.jpg" format="jpg">
<image href="repairthumbs/tss00168.jpg"/>
</xref>
                  </fig>
               </stepxmp>
            </step>
            <step>
               <cmd>Some content for the step</cmd>
            </step>
            <step>
               <cmd>Some content for the step</cmd>
               <stepxmp>
                  <fig>
                     <xref href="repairimages/tss00169.jpg" format="jpg">
<image href="repairthumbs/tss00169.jpg"/>
</xref>
                  </fig>
               </stepxmp>
            </step>
            <step>
               <cmd>Some content for the step</cmd>
               <stepxmp>
                  <fig>
                     <xref href="repairimages/tss00170.jpg" format="jpg">
<image href="repairthumbs/tss00170.jpg"/>
</xref>
                  </fig>
               </stepxmp>
            </step>
         </steps>
      </taskbody>
   </task>
   <task id="d1e41258">
      <title><ph conref="../../resources/SM-reuse.dita#topic_nsx_hq3_sl/installation-title"/></title>
      <taskbody>
         <steps>
            <step>
               <cmd><ph
                     conref="../../resources/SM-reuse.dita#topic_nsx_hq3_sl/Install-Reverse-Except"
                  /></cmd>
               <info>
                  <note conref="../../resources/SM-reuse.dita#topic_nsx_hq3_sl/Solvents-Ventilated"/>
                  <note conref="../../resources/SM-reuse.dita#topic_nsx_hq3_sl/Clean-Before-Install"/>
               </info>
            </step>
            <step>
               <cmd>Some content for the step</cmd>
            </step>
         </steps>
      </taskbody>
   </task>
</task>
```

I am using a file list XML as input for processing multiple source files that looks like this:

```
<directory name="source" size="327680" lastModified="1416254183623" date="20141117T115623" absolutePath="C:\transform_lab\service_manual_projects\frt_work\source" sort="name" reverse="false">
   <file name="12V_Positive_Jump_Post_(Remove_and_Replace).xml" size="3690" lastModified="1415930118927" date="20141113T175518" absolutePath="C:\transform_lab\service_manual_projects\frt_work\source\12V_Positive_Jump_Post_(Remove_and_Replace).xml"/>
   <file name="200A_Fuses_-_Wall_Connector_(Remove_and_Replace).xml" size="12837" lastModified="1415930118958" date="20141113T175518" absolutePath="C:\transform_lab\service_manual_projects\frt_work\source\200A_Fuses_-_Wall_Connector_(Remove_and_Replace).xml"/>
   <file name="2nd_Row_Center_Console_Assembly_(Remove_and_Replace).xml" size="2552" lastModified="1415930118990" date="20141113T175518" absolutePath="C:\transform_lab\service_manual_projects\frt_work\source\2nd_Row_Center_Console_Assembly_(Remove_and_Replace).xml"/>
   <file name="3_Way_Coolant_Valve_-_Chiller_Bypass_(Remove_and_Replace).xml" size="3788" lastModified="1415930119021" date="20141113T175519" absolutePath="C:\transform_lab\service_manual_projects\frt_work\source\3_Way_Coolant_Valve_-_Chiller_Bypass_(Remove_and_Replace).xml"/>
   ...
</directory>
```

The style sheet I've developed looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match ="directory">
    <service-manual>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="file"/> 
    </service-manual>        
</xsl:template >

<xsl:template match="file">     
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="document($path)/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="/*">
            <procedure>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </name>
                <frt-num>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@id,'X')"/>
                </frt-num>                    
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//cmd"/>
            </procedure>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//cmd">
    <xsl:for-each select="xref">
        <child-proc>
            <frt-num>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@keyref,'X')"/>
            </frt-num>                
            <xsl:apply-templates select="file"/>
        </child-proc>            
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Obviously, this is wrong. My thought was that I should create a template that processes the xref nodes and then call that template from the //cmd template but that didn't work much better. Is that the direction I should be taking with this? Also, is using modes an option here? Being that I'm a bit of an amateur, the logic involved with successfully accomplishing this has my brain twisted up a bit. Any help appreciated.

One approach I thought about but wasn't sure how to make work is using `key()` to do a lookup in the key map that is used to manage linked resources. The value of `@keyref` maps to the value of the `@keya` attribute on `keydef` elements. All `keydef` elements are collected in a map that is separate from the service manual content. The key map for this project looks like this:

```
<map processing-role="resource-only">
    <title>Service Manual Link Map</title>
    <keydef keys="X1234"
       href="../section_maps/topics/3_Way_Coolant_Valve_-_Chiller_Bypass_(Remove_and_Replace).xml"/>
    ...
    <keydef keys="X10040401"
       href="../section_maps/topics/Raise_Vehicle_-_2_Post_Lift.xml"/>
    <keydef keys="X15240701"
       href="../section_maps/topics/Raise_Vehicle_-_4_Post_Lift.xml"/>
    ...
</map>
```

Now that I think about it, any solution I come up with must include a lookup in the key map because that is the only way of knowing for sure to what task a given `@keyref` maps.

Comment: Please show an input XML that is complete - and that we can use to help you. For example, there is no `xref` or `cmd` element in the sample you show.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the post to include the source XML I am using for this.

Comment: Your XML document is still incomplete. Please show an XML that can be used as the input for a transformation.

Comment: I included the full XML for the source file and a sample from the input XML files list.

Comment: Is what I have provided not enough to provide any insight on how I can accomplish what I am attempting here?

Comment: You have already provided a lot of info, the only piece still missing is a sensible expected output. The output sketch you do show contains things like "Procedure A" which of course have nothing to do with the input XML you show. Also, should there be one such output document for each `file` in `directory`?

Comment: Further, does the `id` attribute of a `task` element play any role in this, and do you actually show an example of multiple levels of processes, a `child-proc` inside another `child-proc`? I cannot see one.

Answer (score 0):

Many things are still unclear, but it might be easier for you to comment on an attempted solution. Let me know what I have not quite understood.

I have used your input XML, but I have made changes to the directory file. It now only contains one file reference (since I only have the one you show):

```
<directory name="source" size="327680" lastModified="1416254183623" date="20141117T115623" absolutePath="C:\transform_lab\service_manual_projects\frt_work\source" sort="name" reverse="false">
   <file name="12V_Positive_Jump_Post_(Remove_and_Replace).xml" size="3690" lastModified="1415930118927" date="20141113T175518" absolutePath="C:\transform_lab\service_manual_projects\frt_work\source\12V_Positive_Jump_Post_(Remove_and_Replace).xml"/>
</directory>
```

**Stylesheet**

You can do away with most of the `xsl:for-each` constructs, some of them are just superfluous, others are best replaced with a template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/directory">
        <service-manual>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="file"/> 
        </service-manual>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="file">     
        <xsl:variable name="path" select="@name"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="document($path)/task">
                <procedure>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                    </name>
                    <frt-num>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@id,'X')"/>
                    </frt-num>                    
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </procedure>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xref|task/task">
            <child-proc>
                <frt-num>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@keyref,'X')"/>
                </frt-num>                
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </child-proc>            
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

As you can see, some of the `frt-num` elements are empty, because some of the `xref` elements do not have an `@keyref` attribute. In which case, I suspect, they do not reference another subprocess.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service-manual>
   <procedure>
      <name>3 Way Coolant Valve - Chiller Bypass (Remove and Replace)</name>
      <frt-num>1234</frt-num>
      <child-proc>
         <frt-num/>
         <child-proc>
            <frt-num>10040401</frt-num>
         </child-proc>
         <child-proc>
            <frt-num>15240701</frt-num>
         </child-proc>
         <child-proc>
            <frt-num/>
         </child-proc>
         <child-proc>
            <frt-num/>
         </child-proc>
         <child-proc>
            <frt-num/>
         </child-proc>
      </child-proc>
      <child-proc>
         <frt-num/>
         <child-proc>
            <frt-num>46010000</frt-num>
         </child-proc>
      </child-proc>
   </procedure>
</service-manual>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a crack at this. You are right. I probably left out details about this that would make things more clear. For one, I want the transform to focus solely on 'cmd' elements because those contain cross references ('xref') that are specific to other procedures. I will edit my question and attempt to make things more clear.

Comment: @JasonDavis In your expected output, where do elements like `<frt-num>3456</frt-num>` come from? From other `file`s in `directory`? The `xref` of this task is "10040401", is that number also the ID of a task?

Comment: Correct, the value used in the `@keyref` of an `xref` is also used as the task `@id`. Additionally, the value (minus the inital 'X') is also the FRT number for the corresponding procedure, which is a code used to identify the procedure. So, the `@keyref` on an `xref` maps to a key that points to a specific resource. In this case, it points to a specific `task` with an `@id` that is identical to the `@keyref`.

Comment: @JasonDavis So, to find out whether an `xref` points to a `task` element with further subprocesses itself, you'll have to find that `task` element first, right? Where is it? In the same XML document? In any `file` from the `directory`?

Comment: That is probably another piece in this right? I probably should have included it in my question originally. The `@keyref` maps to a `keydef` element as a `@key`. A map is used to aggregate all the `keydef` elements. It sounds like I would need to do some sort of look up in the key map using the key function perhaps? I'll edit my question to include a sample of the key map.